# Filtering longitudinal data by last recorded event, and counting number of rows that meet criteria (and storing that value)

Tags: r, dplyr, longitudinal

I have some (medical) longitudinal data on the detection (or not) of bronchiectasis.  I wish to count the number of participants with and without bronchiectasis at their latest follow up/check.  I then wish to store the number of patients who do have bronchiectasis and the number who don't.  This is so I can then insert that number/value into a qmd report easily.  (I have other outcomes where I need this method).

Is there a simpler/more accurate method of what I'm doing

Example df

| id | date_of_followup | bronchiectasis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | N |
| 1 | 01/12/2022 | Y |
| 2 | 02/07/2022 | Y |
| 2 | 5/6/2023 | Y |
| 3 | 01/05/2021 | N |
| 3 | 3/12/2022 | N |

This is my current code

```
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(date_of_followup == max(date_of_followup )) %>%
    filter(bronchiectasis=="Y")

bronchiectasisyes <- sum(df1$bronchiectasis == "Y")

df2 <- df%>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(date_of_followup == max(date_of_followup )) %>%
    filter(bronchiectasis=="N")

bronchiectasisno <- sum(df2$bronchiectasis == "N")
```

This gets me the desired outcome, but perhaps is a bit messy and I suspect there is a more elegant/robust method

Comment: With the current format of your `date_of_followup`, the `max(.)` of that is poorly-defined. You need a real `Date`-class object for `max(.)` to operate logically. For example `max(c("01/01/2022", "01/02/2021"))` counterintuitively returns `"01/02/2021"`. Any results you have using that logic is suspect at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the date, filtering for max-per-id, then summarizing:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date_of_followup = as.Date(date_of_followup, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  slice_max(date_of_followup, by = id) %>%
  count(bronchiectasis)
#   bronchiectasis n
# 1              N 1
# 2              Y 2
```

To confirm this is working, see the interim step:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(date_of_followup = as.Date(date_of_followup, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  slice_max(date_of_followup, by = id)
#   id date_of_followup bronchiectasis
# 1  1       2022-01-12              Y
# 2  2       2023-05-06              Y
# 3  3       2022-03-12              N
```

(I'm assuming m/d/Y format for your dates ... fix as appropriate.)